# How can I attach to a process with command line arguments?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I started a Centos process which has been running for several hours now. I used `gcc -g` to build the shared library and executable. I started the gdb process by entering `gdb ./MatchUpAccurate`. Once gdb  starts, I  enter `run -input XXXXXXX -fileloc YYYYY -version 5`.

When I enter `ps -ef`, I see two process id numbers, one for `gdb ./MatchUpAccurate.exe` and another one for `./MatchUpAccurate.exe -input XXXXXXX -fileloc YYYYY -version 5`.

Since the child process has been running for several hours now, I would like attach to it so I can check the value of its variables and to see what instruction it is running currently.

I read some documentation an how to use gdb to attach an already running process. However all the examples have no command line arguments. I was wondering how to use gdb to attach a process with command line arguments. I would to be able to set breakpoints, inspect variable, look at the call stack, and step through the execution path without killing the original process. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

you need to attach to the pid:

`gdb binary_name pid`

alternatively, start gdb and attach

```
user@host ~> gdb binary_name
(gdb) attach 1234
```

Comment: I tried this, But when I enter continue, gdb responds with "The program is not being run". When I enter bt, gdb responds with "No stack". When I enter info args, gdb responds with "No frame selected". When I enter run, gdb asks for the command line arguments. When I run -input xxx -fileloc yyyy -version 5, gdb starts running at the beginning of the program. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: are you running gdb under the same user/privileges of the to-be-debugged process?

Comment: @jweyrich, Yes I am runing gdb under the same user/privileges of the to-be debugged process. Should I be doing that? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: yes, that's the correct way and should work. Anyway, if the target application is trusted, try running gdb as root just in case, but I doubt it makes any difference. If that doesn't work either, I'd risk to say you're passing an invalid PID, or that something is protecting the process from being debugged.

Comment: What Sams should work but if some reason it is not, another strategy is to send the child process a signal that generates a core, like sibabrt.  Then you can load the core file into the debugger. Note that you need to make sure cores are enabled. (ulimit -c)

Comment: @frankc, If I send the child process a signal like SIGABRT, won't that cause the child process to exit? I have been running the child process for several hours now and I don't want to have start it up again. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam,@jweyrich,#frankc I figured out the problem. I originally started the gdb process using gdb ./MatchUpAccurate.exe. When I try to attach to either the gdb process or the MatchUpAccurate.exe child process,I cannot find any information about the child process. Instead, I started the MatchUpAccurate.exe process without gdb and now I can attach it and find all the necessary information. Thank you for help.

Comment: If you are planning to attach, what is the point in specifying the binary name when starting GDB. You can just start it as `gdb` and then do an interactive attach. The command-line version of that is `gdb -p <pid>`

Answer (score 3):

If you start your exe with `gdb` you do not have to attach to it. Just hit `Ctrl-C` and have a look at your variable.

If you want to attach, start your exe :

```
./myexe --myopt myargs
```

get the pid :

```
myexe_pid=$!
```

Then attach :

```
gdb ./myexe $myexe_pid
```

my2c

Comment: neuro, I tried your suggestion for attaching. However, I when start my exe. it starts another process at the very beginning ofthe execution path. In my case, the new proram goes to sleep because it encounters a sqlite database lock. I would really like to to be able to attach to the original already running process and intercept the program state after running for over 3 hours. Thank you.

Comment: then use ps to find the process id of the process you want to attach to, and use gdb with that debugging-enabled executable and pid

Comment: @Chris, Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it and it works. I figured out my original problem. I originally started the gdb process using gdb ./MatchUpAccurate.exe. When I try to attach to either the gdb process or the MatchUpAccurate.exe child process,I cannot find any information about the child process.  Instead, I started the MatchUpAccurate.exe process without gdb and now I can attach it and find all the necessary information. Thank you for help. –

Comment: @frank: Glad you have solved your problem with gdb ... Good luck with your exe problem ;)